# OpenLayers function(mergeNewParams) is overwriting previous function call

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I am trying to parse both the values to the corresponding words to fetch data from GeoServer and return me the value, like this:

```
route.mergeNewParams({viewparams: "'word1:+source;word2:+target"});
```

But its not working. In fact no values(source and target) are being assigned to the respective words(word1, word2). I have also tried it to do this way:

```
route.mergeNewParams({viewparams: "word1:"+source});
route.mergeNewParams({viewparams: "word2:"+target});
```

But in this case last 2nd call of function is overwriting the 1st call.

Comment: Are `source` & `target` string variables? or do you actually want to pass the the string whose value is 'source'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understrand that the parameters that you pass to the `mergeNewParams` function, is infact passed to the OGC Service as a HTTP parameter.

SO whatever parameter you pass, should be a valid HTTP parameters.

I'm assuming that `source` & `target` are two string variables that you want to pass. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
var p="word1:"+source+";word2:"+target;
route.mergeNewParams({"viewparams":encodeURI(p)});
```